Hibernate 6 is storing Instant in UTC instead of EST with timestamp without timezone
I recently upgraded my Spring Boot application from Hibernate 5 to Hibernate 6 and encountered an issue where timestamps are now being stored in UTC in my PostgreSQL database, despite my JVM and database being configured for EST.
Application Setup:

Database column type: timestamp without time zone
Entity field type: Instant
Hibernate version: 6.4.1.Final
Entity:

@Entity
public class AppConfig {

    public AppConfig() {
        this.setCreatedDate(Instant.now());  // Capturing current time in UTC
    }

    @Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false)
    private Instant createdDate;
}

Problem:
Before the upgrade to Hibernate 6, the Instant was converted to the local time (EST) and stored correctly in the timestamp without timezone column. However, after upgrading to Hibernate 6, the timestamps are now being stored in UTC.
I tried setting the below properties in application.properties as per Hibernate migration doc but it did not help:
            hibernate.timezone.default_storage: NORMALIZE
            hibernate.jdbc.time_zone: America/New_York

Example:
Expected value in DB (EST): 2024-10-03 14:30:00
Actual value stored in DB (UTC): 2024-10-03 19:30:00

How can I configure Hibernate to store the timestamp in the local time (EST) as before?

You are using the wrong data type for your column in the database. The Postgres type TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE represents only a date with time-of-day but lacks the context of a time zone or offset from UTC. So that type is inherently ambiguous. So that type cannot represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline. In contrast, the Java class Instant does represent a moment, a point on the timeline as seen from an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC. An Instant is not ambiguous. So it makes no sense for you to be mapping TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE to Instant.

While I agree with it being ambiguous, due to compatibility of my application and since it was supported in Hibernate 5, is there a way to achieve the same legacy behavior? As per migration doc, above settings should do that, but that dint work. @BasilBourque
